# Ajax POST works in Desktop but not in Phonegap App or Android

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova

I have this GLOBAL function that is not working in Phonegap Desktop app or Chrome Mobile at Android, it works only in Chrome PC version...i call this function with an onClick event, `#suich` is a switch checkbox SVG

```
function setPush() {
    var nick_ = window.localStorage.getItem("username");
    var notify = window.localStorage.getItem("option");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "push_set.php",
        data: ({
            nick: nick_,
            opcion: notify
        }),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                if (notify == 1) {
                    myApp.alert('Notifications disabled', 'Notice:');
                    $('#suich').prop('checked', false);
                } else {
                    myApp.alert('Notifications enabled', 'Notice:');
                    $('#suich').prop('checked', true);
                }
            } else if (data.status == 'error')
                alert('Connection problems', 'Warning:');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you post the full HTML page...

Answer (score 3):

try to put full url instead of

```
url: "push_set.php"
```

like

```
url: "www.yourdomain.com/push_set.php"
```